# Finding equation of a curve given the gradient of the tangent to the curve

Tags: calculus, integration

If the gradient of the tangent to a curve is given by $2x+1$ and the curve passes through the point $(-3,0)$, find the equation of the curve.

Shouldn't it be the equation of the tangent to the curve since the gradient in a linear equation of the form $ax+b$ is represented by $a$?

Comment: I think the question means that you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with a derivative $f'(x) = 2x+1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and you also know $f(-3)=0$.  So then find the function.

Comment: Got the function $y=x^2+x-6$, but when I graphed both functions, I got two intersections. As seen here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x6vttaawgl

Answer (score 1):

You're given: $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+1$

By simple integration you obtain:

$$y=x^2+x-6$$

Now, you say that:

> Got the function [...], but when I graphed both functions, I got two intersections

This is obviously a misunderstood claim. The expression $2x+1$ gives you the **slope** of the tangent at a point $x$ of the graph, it does NOT give you the **equation** of the tangent at that point.

For a comparison, at point $P(-3,0)$, the *slope* of the tangent is $m=2\cdot(-3)+1=-5$ and so, the *equation* of the tangent is $y-0=-5\cdot(x-(-3))$. You can verify it from graph as well:

[image]

Also, note that different points of the curve will have *different slopes* and correspondingly *different equations* for tangents.

The line $y=2x+1$, thus, is in no way a "tangent" to the graph of $y$.

Hope your query is clarified!